# Raid-50 Status Degraded

Tags: dell-poweredge

I have a server Dell R710 with raid controller PERC 6/i integrated. I have a configuration of 6 X 500 hard drives with RAID-50. Last night I noticed one issue with my drive 5 and it went down without any notice and the server shows status DEGRADED in raid controller and the drive just shows missing. I have tried removing it and reinstalling more than 2-3 times and the drive powers up but does not show in system. I tried replacing a new drive hoping I would rebuild it but when I go to raid controller with the new drive it shows status READY and only gives the option of Global Hot Spare and no option of rebuild is available. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According this thread: https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/Perc-6-i-1-disk-replaced-how-to-rebuild-RAID-5/td-p/4606449
You should add the new drive as a global hot spare and then it should be able to transition to Rebuild state. You should do it from the contoller BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation can be problematic.

Putting a new drive in and marking it as hot spare can change the RAID disk ID and make the system unbootable/unreadable specially if you are under a VM host.

You can rebuild after marking it as hot spare but make sure to backup all your data first, to make sure you have no surprises.

You can do the rebuild either from BIOS or Dell's management interface (if you configured one when setting up the server initially).